# Opposite of absolute convergent test

Tags: real-analysis

So we know that by the absolute convergence test, if $\sum |a_k|$ converges, then $\sum a_k$ converges.

But, is it true that if we have $\sum |a_k|$ diverges, then $\sum a_k $diverges?

**EDIT:** In one of this complex series problem on finding the values of z for when the series $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{z^n}{1+z^{2n}}$$

Now in the solution for the case when $|z|=1$ we have the following computation:

$$\bigg|\frac{z^n}{1+z^{2n}}\bigg|\ge\frac{1}{2}$$

Now the part I am confused about is, in the solution it says $\frac{z^n}{1+z^{2n}}$ cannot converge to $0$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$ hence the series must diverge for when $|z|=1$. Why doesn't it converge to $0$? How can we show this part more rigorously?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Consider the alternating harmonic series $\sum (-1)^n\tfrac{1}{n}$.

Comment: I have edited my question further, I would appreciate further help.

Comment: Any convergent series has the property that its terms go to $0$. However, yours stay away from $1/2$, so your series must diverge.

Comment: I get that fact which is from the term test, but the absolute value stays away from $1/2$. So does that imply the complex sequence term inside the absolute value also stay away from $1/2?$ This is the part I am confused about.

Comment: I should have been more precise - it stays at least $1/2$ away from $0$, in absolute value. So all the terms are outside the open disc centered at $0$ of radius $1/2$.

Comment: Yes that makes alot more sense intuitively, thank you, thinking using the disk really helps !

Answer (score 1):

If $$\frac{z^n}{1+z^{2n}}$$ converged to zero as $n$ goes to infinity, then, according to the very definition, its absolute value would, if you take a large enough $n$, be smaller than 1/3. Your computation proves this to be impossible.

So it does not converge to zero.

Let now $$u_N=\sum_{n=0}^N \frac{z^n}{1+z^{2n}},$$ if your series did converge, the sequence $(u_n)$ would converge to some finite limit, and so $$\frac{z^n}{1+z^{2n}} = u_n - u_{n-1}$$ would go to zero as $n$ goes to infinity. We get a contradiction again.

Answer (score 0):

No it is not true, consider

$$\sum (-1)^n \frac1n$$

then $\sum \left|(-1)^n \frac1n\right|=\sum \frac1n$ diverges but $\sum (-1)^n \frac1n$ converges.

Comment: I have edited my question further, I would appreciate the help.

Comment: In the given example the necessary condition $a_n\to 0$ is not satisfied.

Answer (score 0):

Concerning your edit: Check the square of the absolute value of your term by multiplying with the complex conjugate:

$$\bigg|\frac{z^n}{1+z^{2n}}\bigg|^2=\frac{z^n}{1+z^{2n}}\cdot\frac{\left(z^*\right)^{n}}{1+\left(z^*\right)^{2n}}\\
= \frac{|z|^{2n}}{1+z^{2n}+\left(z^*\right)^{2n}+|z|^{4n}}$$

Now we are using $z=e^{i\varphi}$ since $|z|=1$:

$$\bigg|\frac{z^n}{1+z^{2n}}\bigg|^2=\frac{1}{1+e^{2in\varphi}+e^{-2in\varphi}+1}\\
=\frac{1}{2+2\cos(2n\varphi)}
\geq\frac{1}{4}$$

because the denominator is upward bound by $\cos(x)\leq1$. Thus, by drawing the square root, we get:

$$\bigg|\frac{z^n}{1+z^{2n}}\bigg|\geq\frac{1}{2}$$